# Can I call C or C++ functions from Rust code?

Tags: c++, c, rust

Is it possible to call C or C++ functions within Rust? If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 27):

Rust doesn't support this directly, C++ function symbol mangling is implementation defined, so it will need a lot of support from Rust to handle this feature. It's not impossible but it's probably not going to happen.

However, Rust claims to support the C language. This is clearly more easy to support, as it "only" needs to support the function calls of C. This is implementation-defined behavior too, but this doesn't change a lot and people agree to work together to share the same convention so you will not have a problem to use C as intermediary on common platform.

So, to call C++ from Rust, you must pass by C.

To call C from Rust, [the docs show this example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html#using-extern-functions-to-call-external-code):

```rust
extern "C" {
    fn abs(input: i32) -> i32;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        println!("Absolute value of -3 according to C: {}", abs(-3));
    }
}
```

To call C++ from C, a C++ function must be defined like [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage):

```cpp
// This C++ function can be called from C code
extern "C" void handler(int) {
    std::cout << "Callback invoked\n"; // It can use C++
}
```

To transmute this example to our example in Rust, that gives:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cinttypes>

extern "C" std::int32_t abs(std::int32_t n) {
    return std::abs(static_cast<std::intmax_t>(n));
}
```

Comment: `// It can use C++` - just to be sure - it can't accept C++ types (such as `std::string`), nor return them, right?

Comment: @Marc.2377 yes and no, you can't directly "share" c++ type but you can give to the c part a `void *` C can't use it but can give it back to c++ part, and then c++ can cast it to the real type.

Comment: @Stargateur how do you get that `void *` from the Rust object? You might be able to get a `char*`, but C++ and Rust strings almost certainly have an compatible layout

Comment: @OrangeDog the std::string in c++ and string in rust are completely different and don't work together. You need to either create a struct in rust to fake the memory layout of a c++ string and manipulate it through the dummy struct [or vice versa] (not recommended possibly compiler dependent) better work with char* which c++ and rust can convert into strings. But keep in mind rust strings are not \0 terminated.

Answer (score 14):

Rust can link to/call C functions via its [FFI](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html), but not C++ functions.

While I don't know why you can't call C++ functions, it is probably because C++ functions are [complicated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B).

Comment: You can just define C linkage on any C++ function, making it available from C and thus also Rust. ```extern "C"``` is your friend here.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to call C functions from **libc** there is a rust crate that allows writing C like code directly in rust, some of it requires unsafe blocks.

Below is an example of seting the nofile system limit. Instructions for this code are in `man 2 setrlimit`, i.e. the code maps almost directly from C to rust.

```
use libc::rlimit;
use libc::setrlimit;
use libc::RLIMIT_NOFILE;

/// Set system limits on number of "open files"
pub fn increase_rlimit_nofile(limit: u64) -> i32 {
    let lim = rlimit {
        rlim_cur: limit,
        rlim_max: limit
    };
    unsafe {
        let rv: i32 = setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &lim);
        return rv;
    }
}
```